# i have mongodb query which work on mongo playground but dont work on my code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this model

```
const registerSchema = new Schema(
   {
UserName: {
  type: String,
  requires: true,
},
Contact: {
  type: String,
  requires: false,
},
Email: {
  type: String,
  requires: false,
},
Password: {
  type: String,
  requires: true,
},
RoleCode: {
  type: String,
  enum: ["001", "111", "222"], // 001-user, 111-manager, 222-admin
  requires: true,
},
openingHours: [
  {
    day: {
      type: Number,
    },
    startTime: {
      type: Number,
    },
    endTime: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
], }, { timestamps: true });
```

i want to check the opening hour.When the user want to book the futsal slot i want check whether the user starttime and endTime is fall inside this opening hour.

i have write query code as

```
const inOpeningHours = await Register.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: managerId,
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$openingHours", // Unwind the openingHours array
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          $and: [
            {
              "openingHours.day": {
                $eq: reservationData.startTime.getDay(),
              },
            },
            {
              "openingHours.startTime": {
                $gt: reservationData.startTime.getHours(),
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          $and: [
            {
              "openingHours.day": {
                $eq: reservationData.endTime.getDay(),
              },
            },
            {
              "openingHours.endTime": {
                $lt: reservationData.endTime.getHours(),
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
]);
```

but this query doesn't work well. When i give the time that doesnt fall between opening hours, This query doesnt check whether the time is inside the opening hour or not.

Comment: You must exchange `$gt` and `$lt` (or maybe better `$gte` and `$lte`). Take a piece of paper and draw a timeline. Mark the points of your input data and opening hours, then you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition must be like this:

```
{
   $match: {
      "openingHours.day": reservationData.startTime.getDay(),
      "openingHours.startTime": { $lte: reservationData.startTime.getHours() },
      "openingHours.endTime": { $gte: reservationData.endTime.getHours() }
   }
}
```

There is no need for complex boolean logic.

Depending on your requirements you should prefer [$filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead of `$unwind` and `$match`, would give better performance.